# Nested Scopes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

**Nested Scopes in AngularJS**

Is it possible create nested scopes that do not inherit properties from their parent scope

Comment: Check this: https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They are called isolate scopes. You can create it manually via

```
$scope.$new(true)
```

The new scope will have `$parent` property which resolves to parent scope, but it will not have prototypal inheritance from parent.

More about isolate scopes [in official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new)